# What does this condition do in ternary?

Tags: javascript

**Javascript Ternary Condition**

I have javascript with this condition, what is this?

```
var y = (typeof x !== undefined) ? x || 0 : 1;
```

Comment: The condition fails to do what is intended because it will always be `true`.

Comment: yes

var y = (typeof x !== undefined) ? x || 0 : 1;

Comment: If `x` is not defined, then it will return 1. If `x` is defined, then it will return `0` if `x` is falsy, otherwise it returns the value of `x`.

Comment: To check undefined, do `x !== undefined`. It's vastly safer. Using `typeof` for this purpose is problematic for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `(typeof x !== undefined) ? x || 0 : 1;` is going to return always `true` because the `typeof` operator will return a `string`.

**That condition should compare a string as follow:**

```
(typeof x !== 'undefined') ? x || 0 : 1;
```

```js
var x;
var str = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x || 0 : 1;

console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Conditional (ternary) Operator explanation:**

```
                         +--- When condition is true
                         |
                         |        +--- When condition is false
                         |        |
                         |        |
                         v        v
typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x || 0 : 1;
  ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                             |
  |                             +---- The condition should be:
  |                                   (x === undefined ? 1 : x || 0)
  |
  +--- Checks for the type of x
```

## Code refactored

```js
var x = 4;
var str = x === undefined ? 1 : x || 0;
console.log(str);// should return 4

var y;
str = y === undefined ? 1 : y || 0;
console.log(str);// should return 1

y = null;
str = y === undefined ? 1 : y || 0;
console.log(str);// should return 0

y = 5;
str = y === undefined ? 1 : y || 0;
console.log(str);// should return 5

y = 5-"5";
str = y === undefined ? 1 : y || 0;
console.log(str); // should return 0
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Docs

- [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: Why correct the bad code that led to the bug? Just do a proper comparison to `undefined` so you're not perpetuating bad coding.

Comment: That's a good catch, but you still need to explain the reset of the ternary, which was really what the question was about.

Comment: The question is asking specifically about the condition, which is what Ele is answering.

Comment: *"This OR is unnecessary because x will be 
                                           a value different than undefined, so the condition
                                           should be (typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 1)
                                         even better, switch the condition to:
                                           (typeof x === 'undefined' ? 1 : x)"* That's incorrect. There are multiple values that could trigger the right hand side of the `||`.

Comment: @doodlemeister can you explain which ones?

Comment: All "falsey" values. `undefined`, `NaN`, `false`, `""`, `0`, `null`.

Comment: ...the continued use of `typeof x === "undefined"`  in the reworked code is unfortunate.

Comment: @doodlemeister post an answer with your recommendations.

Comment: @Ele: No, people rarely want to hear information that makes them think.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an error with the condition:

```
(typeof x !== undefined)
```

because you are comparing a ***type*** against a ***value***.

**[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)** always returns a string, while `undefined` is a value. So, whatever type `x` is, it will be returned as as string. Even if it's value is `undefined`, `"undefined"` (notice the quotes?) will be returned as its type and since the string `"undefined"` has a `typeof === "string"`, the condition will actually branch into the `true` section, even when `x` actually *is* `undefined`.

So, it needs to be: `(typeof x !== "undefined")`.

Or, you could test the ***value*** of `x` against the ***value*** `undefined`:

```
(x !== undefined)
```

But, you can't mix and match values and types.

---

Now, assuming we correct that, the next part (the `true` branch):

```
x || 0
```

Simply returns `x`, as long as it is not **["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)** (that is, any value that would convert to the Boolean `false`). `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `""` or `null` are all falsy. So, if `x` is not falsy, `x` is returned. If `x` is falsy, then `0` is returned. This is a way to provide a default return value in case the first value doesn't exist. **But, the logic is a bit off here**, because if the code has entered the `true` branch, it's because `x` is not `undefined`, which means it's **["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)**. And, if it's truthy, then we can safely just return `x`. So, it really should just be:

```
x
```

Finally, the last part (the `false` branch)

```
1
```

Is what will be returned if the original condition is `false`. In this case, if `x` is `undefined`.

So, the code has flaws in it and really should be:

```
(typeof x  !== "undefined") ? x : 1
```

**EXTRA CREDIT:**

In reality, any expression you place into the condition of an `if` statement is going to be converted to a Boolean for the `if` to do its job. If all you need to know is if `x` is not a "falsy" value, then all you need to do is write:

```
x ? x : 1;
```

The `x` will be converted to a Boolean.
If it's `true` (truthy), then `x` is returned.
If it's `false` (falsy), then `1` is returned.

**Examples:**

```js
function testX(x){
  return x ? x : 1;
}

// Truthy:
console.log(testX(10));           // 10
console.log(testX({}));           // {}
console.log(testX(true));         // true
console.log(testX("something"));  // "something"

// Falsy:
console.log(testX(""));     // 1
console.log(testX());       // 1
console.log(testX(4-"Z"));  // 1 because 4-"Z" == NaN
console.log(testX(false));  // 1
console.log(testX(0));      // 1
console.log(testX(null));   // 1
```

Comment: I believe that `(false || 0) === 0`, so that's another value that is not undefined or null

Comment: "But, the logic is a bit off here, because if the code has entered the true branch, it's because x is not undefined, which means it's truthy."
 This part is wrong. the initial condition can indeed be improved but in case of `x === NaN`, returning `x || 0` is useful

Comment: @Logar I don't see how that is true. See my examples at the end of my answer. There is a `NaN` test in there and the code works as it should. If `x === NaN`, why would you want to return `x`?

Comment: This `testX(4-"Z")` should return `0` according to the OP's approach.

Comment: @Logar is correct. When entering the "true branch" of the conditional operator, the only thing we know about `x` is that it is not `undefined`, and as you state, there are multiple "falsey" values beyond `undefined`. So you're  contradicting yourself within the same paragraph.

Comment: ...and the "extra credit" `x ? x : 1;` could be better written as `x || 1;`, but I think it's pretty clear that that's not the OP's intent, since they're substituting `0` for a reason. As written, with the `undefined` check corrected, any falsey value other than `undefined` should assign `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
(typeof x !== undefined)
```

asks if `x` is not of type `undefined`. Or, if `x` is defined. This will include any value or even `null`.

```
...? x || 0
```

If so, the expression evaluates to this. Which is the value of `x` in most cases or `0` if `x` is anything evaluated to be boolean `false`, e.g., `null`, `false`, etc.

```
... : 1;
```

Otherwise (i.e. case when `x` is undefined), evaluates to `1`.

Typing in Javascript is complicated (in my opinion), sometimes it is not easy to remember what it is when you're comparing mixed type stuff, see https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ for a summary matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Admitting that you have a left-hand operand, it does the same thing as :

```
var y;
if(typeof x !== undefined) {
    if(x)
        y = x;
    else
        y = 0;
}
else
    y = 1;
```

Comment: `undefined != "undefined"`

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Logar didn't say it was. This answer accurately represents what happens and says nothing of what the result will be.

Comment: Yes, this has been stated in the 2 other answers and they are more detailed than mine. I was just strictly answering OP's question

Comment: The answer should address the mistake in the original code. That's just how good answers work on SO.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't want to change OP's original code in my example, nor do I want to add the precision as I didn't catch it in the first place and your answer as well as Ele's (which are more voted and more precise anyway) already took care of that. Imho this downvote is not deserved, but I can live with it

Comment: I'm just trying to help you understand how [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) work on SO. Each answer should be complete. What happens if another answer which states something that you didn't gets removed from SO in the future? You have to remember that SO is not just a place for one person to get their question answered, it's a knowledge base for people with similar questions in the future. Each answer should be as complete as possible. The down vote is warranted because it's an incentive for you to write a better answer.